# WHERE clause on individual rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, where-clause

I'm trying to write a query that will select rows from a table but I'm struggling a little with there WHERE clause.

I have a list of C# objects that has an ID and a Date. I want to find rows in my database where the ID is equal to one of the ids in my list of objects, but at the same time, the Date that comes with the specific ID has to be between a ValidFrom and a ValidTo field in the Database.

I already a query that will work but it is not a very pretty solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[Employees] AS emp
WHERE emp.IsDeleted = 0
AND (emp.EmployeeId = 1
AND (emp.ValidFrom <= '2017-05-01')
AND (emp.ValidTo > '2017-05-01'))

OR (emp.EmployeeId = 2
AND (emp.ValidFrom <= '2018-05-01')
AND (emp.ValidTo > '2018-05-01'))
```

And then I'd proceed to add the 'OR' statement from there.

Is there a more optimal way for me to accomplish this?

Comment: You are using too many unnecessary parenthesis.

Comment: Ah that is true, nice catch! Is there another way of doing it though, without having to repeat the OR statement a thousand times?

Comment: Where does the different date literals come from? Shouldn't they be found in another table? And JOIN that table?

Comment: The dates are provided from an external API, so I cannot join on that table :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can populate the filtering criteria in a separate table:

```
CREATE TABLE #RecordsTobeFiltered
(
    EmployeeId INT
   ,ValidFrom DATE
   ,ValidTo DATE
);

INSERT INTO #RecordsTobeFiltered (EmployeeId, ValidFrom, ValidTo)
VALUES (1, '2017-05-01', '2017-05-01')
      ,(2, '2018-05-01', '2018-05-01')
      --- and many records as you need


SELECT * 
FROM [dbo].[Employees] AS emp
INNER JOIN #RecordsTobeFiltered F
    ON emp.EmployeeId = f.EmployeeId
    and emp.ValidFrom <= f.ValidFrom
    and emp.validTo >  f.ValidTo
WHERE emp.IsDeleted = 0;
```